# ember.js best way to load multiple css and js files

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I am creating an ember application. Right now I am loading all the js and css files in index.html file like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/gumby.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/global.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=assets/css/tooltipster.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/about.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/admin.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/global_print.css" media="print" />
```

js files:

```
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/router.js"></script>
<script src="js/account.js"></script>
<script src="js/message.js"></script>
<script src="js/user.js"></script>
<script src="js/inquiry.js"></script>
```

I know its not a best practice to load all the js and css files when the application start. I wanted to how other people doing for their application and whats the best way to do it.

Comment: Best practice doesn't say anything about not loading them all when the application starts.  You would be wise to bundle your javascript and css files thought to reduce calls to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the generally accepted approach is that stylesheets go at the top, and javascript dependancies go at the bottom, which seems to be how you have it organized.

Aside from WHERE in your file you request these files, keep in mind that each individual script or link tag is an individual call back to the server. 17 trips back and forth, not including images, etc., could be a real speed bump to your user.

Have you considered using Ember-CLI for your project? (http://www.ember-cli.com) It makes stuff like this -so- much easier. It will bundle all your libraries and stylesheets for you, and save you a lot of time. Even more so if you use preprocessors for your stylesheets or javascript.

If you're not so inclined to use Ember-CLI, there are a variety of utilities and websites that will compress your dependancies for you.